Difference between usememo and React.memo with example
What is the difference between useMemo and React.memo? in which case the React.memo is used? and in which case the useMemo will be used? i have googled for a perfect example to show when the react.memo is used but i cant able to find

You can use memo when you don't want any child component can render without change in prop (consider memo as pureComponent) and useMemo is used to cache the value between renders

React.memo:

Memoizes an entire functional component to prevent unnecessary re-renders.
Relies on props for comparison, performs shallow comparison by default.

useMemo:

Memoizes specific computations or values within a functional component
Explicitly specifies dependencies in an array
Avoids expensive recalculations if dependencies haven't changed

